# Get which of create, update or delete statements triggered Querydatabasetable in nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, mysql-connector

In my project I am synchronizing neo4j data with mysql by using nifi to connect to kafka and neo4j plugin `Streams` to bring the data from kafka to neo4j. Inside nifi I have this structure

```
Querydatabasetable -> UpdateAttribute -> PublishKafkaRecord
```

It triggers on any change and gets updated data, but to be able to optimize my neo4j code I need to know the type of query triggered in sql (insert, update, delete). It seems that I can't get it with `Querydatabasetable` processor, so which processor I should use for that purpose?

Comment: Take a look at CaptureChangeMySQL, it should give you that kind of information.

Comment: yea I am configuring certificate for using CaptureChangeMySQL. Will answer to this question when I test it (if no one answers). Thanks!